# How to adjust headphone gain in /sys/kernel/sound_control/headphone_gain?

Tags: audio, android

I want to increase headphone gain. So I have found the file location at `/sys/kernel/sound_control/headphone_gain`.

```
cat /sys/kernel/sound_control/headphone_gain
```

shows

```
0 0
```

For writing some desired value like 226, I tried:

```
echo "226 226" > /sys/kernel/sound_control/headphone_gain
```

But reading still returns `0 0`.

How to write `226 226` to it?

Comment: I am already root.

Comment: You're already in `/`  right, not just missing the leading slash in `/sys/kernel/sound_control/headphone_gain`? And it's definitely a writeable setting, it's not read-only / for information only?

Comment: Jonny789 does that mean your issue has been resolved, or is there still a question you want to ask?

Comment: Not yet resolved.

Comment: You should add details, such as what system are you using (and possibly what sound system you are using).

Comment: There's very little documentation on this that I can find. However the [one](https://gist.github.com/maz-1/9261a097e128c6aedb71c68a58909299) example I can find of accessing it uses a variation on a signed value, such that values exceeding 172 need to have 256 subtracted from them. In your case, the value 226 should be represented as -30. No, I don't know why.

Comment: This isn't an unclear question, although it would benefit from a kernel version number (`uname -a`).

Comment: Is this on Android? I've never seen this path on x86 Linux. I'd guess permissible values depend on whatever kernel module is at the other end, so the obvious approach is "identify your kernel flavour, find source code for your kernel, find kernel module (`lsmod` may or may not help), read module source code and see what values you can put there". Starting with `1 0`, `0 1`, `0 0` etc. and see if those values are accepted is another thing I'd try.

Comment: Yes . It is android. Using kernel adiutor app , I found that valid values are from -40 to 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I should be writing signed values as explained by [roaima](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469702/how-to-adjust-headphone-gain-in-sys-kernel-sound-control-headphone-gain/470189#comment856940_469702):

> There's very little documentation on this that I can find. However the one example I can find of accessing it uses a variation on a signed value, such that values exceeding 172 need to have 256 subtracted from them. In your case, the value 226 should be represented as -30. No, I don't know why.

Writing `-30 -30` woks:

```
# echo "-30 -30" > /sys/kernel/sound_control/headphone_gain
# cat  /sys/kernel/sound_control/headphone_gain
226  226
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. In future, please edit your original question to include any relevant details instead of writing them in the answer.